# Forbidden error in post request when use postman, but not in curl

Tags: curl, request, postman

Why do I get a "forbidden" response from the postman, but response is correct if I use the curl command in the terminal?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have empty body in postman

Comment: Parameters in query used only with GET method. Try move parameters to body.

Answer (score 1):

my best guess is that in curl you're sending the username and password in JSON-format, and in postman you're sending the username and password in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format, and your target API does not understand the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`-format. (that said, your screenshot does not say which format you're sending the credentials in, but i think Postman's default format is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)

in any case, consult the API documentation about which format the login request should be encoded in (but going by your functional curl invocation, JSON *is* a supported format)